# Pymongo does not recognize $cond

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My Pymongo is 3.2.1, and from the documentation it should take in `$cond` without any issue.

The syntax of `$cond` is

```
{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }
```

and my query is:

```
{'$and': [{u'$cond': [{u'activity': {u'$in': [u'specialLogin',
                                        u'moreSpecialLogin']}},
                  {u'$or': [{u'log_type': u'user'}],
                   u'tags': u'Login AND NOT badLogin',
                   u'time': {u'$gt': 10}},
                  {u'$or': [{u'log_type': u'admin'},
                            {u'log_type': u'user'}],
                   u'tags': u'Login AND NOT badLogin',
                   u'time': {u'$gt': 10}}],
       'time': {'$gt': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 29, 19, 27, 49, 491065)}},
      {'log_type': {'$ne': 'alert'}}]}
```

so my if-condition would be

```
{u'activity': {u'$in': [u'specialLogin', u'moreSpecialLogin']}}
```

if true:

```
{u'$or': [{u'log_type': u'user'}],
 u'tags': u'Login AND NOT badLogin',
 u'time': {u'$gt': 10}}
```

if false:

```
{u'$or': [{u'log_type': u'admin'},
          {u'log_type': u'user'}],
 u'tags': u'Login AND NOT badLogin',
 u'time': {u'$gt': 10}}
```

I've been getting this error

```
OperationFailure: unknown top level operator: $cond
```

It seems to me the pymongo does not recognize $cond, but from documentation the $cond comment (and the format) is there since mongodb 2.6

Can anyone spot the issue? I'm running out of luck here.

Comment: I don't understand what your are try to do but I call tell you that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: thus the question......